# Django models.Manager custom SQL query "more than one row returned" error

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

So I'm trying to get the result of the age() function on PostgreSQL from a column in the DB.

The goal is to append a new virtual column with the age or time elapsed since the datetime stored the database.

I tried this by creating a models.Manager in Django to add this new column:

```
class PriorityManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        time_elapsed = RawSQL('SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(datetime)) AS age FROM backend_post',
                               params=(),
                               output_field=models.IntegerField())
    return super(PriorityManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(score=time_elapsed)
```

I need a score column to help sort the objects later, and the score is based on the time elapsed.

The query `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(datetime)) AS age FROM backend_post;` works in the dbshell but when running it on Django, the following message comes up:

> ProgrammingError at /api/post/list/ more than one row returned by a
>   subquery used as an expression

I suspect the problem is that the query returns a whole column of elements while the models.Manager expected only one result. I believe there should be something sent as a parameter in the RawSQL query but I couldn't figure out what it is...

Anyone knows what to do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by using

http://django-postgres-stats.readthedocs.io/

It allows for many custom postgres functions with django, just what I needed. Don't know why it took me so long to find it!